# Substring is found, but regex fails

Tags: java, regex

Suppose I have some string, and run the following tests on it:

```
response.indexOf("</p:panelGrid>");
response.matches(".*</p:panelGrid>.*");
```

How is it possible that `indexOf` finds the substring (it does not return `-1`), but the regular expression in the second test does **not** match?

I have come across this problem while trying to write a test that checks if taglibs are rendered correctly in JSF with Pax Web. I have not been able to reproduce this behavior outside of this test.

Comment: You probably have escape characters.

Comment: Provide a String that exhibits such behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.` matches everything except for newline characters. You must change your regex string to

```
"(?s).*</p:panelGrid>.*"
```

Then it will match always.